# Merging two querying

Tags: sql, oracle

I will introduce my problem with a simple example.

I have two generic queries on the same table, say table 'customers'

[image]

Defined 'plushes' a table containing information about in-store plushes, the following first query retrieves for a certain subset of Customers, say first subset, their preferred plush.

```
WITH preferences 
AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID,
    CustomerName,
    City,
    Country,
    PlushType,
    PlushPrice

    FROM customers cs
    LEFT JOIN plushes ps
    ON cs.CustomerID = ps.CustomerID

    WHERE cs.CustomerID < 4

)

SELECT CustomerID, PlushType, PlushPrice
FROM preferences
```

In the same way, defined 'dishes' a table containing world famous dishes, the second query retrieve for a *another* subset of Customers, say second subset, their preferred dish.

```
    WITH foodPreferences 
AS
(
    SELECT CustomerID,
    CustomerName,
    City,
    Country,
    FoodName,
    FoodPrice

    FROM customers cs
    LEFT JOIN foods fs
    ON cs.CustomerID = fs.CustomerID

    WHERE fs.FoodName = 'pizza'  

)

SELECT CustomerID, FoodName
FROM foodPreferences -- it returns customer 6
```

What I am searching for, is a query that shows customerID, plushType, plushPrice for the customers of the first OR the second subset, i.e. :

[image]

That means, I would like to apply the first query to the first OR a second  (deriving from another query) subset. 
In other words, I want to run the first query for those customers who love pizza.

I am using OracleDB, with PL/Sql language.

Any idea?

P.s. I know that for the written example the structure of the used queries appears weird. Indeed, I am working with something more complex and I preferred to mirror the structure of the query I have

Comment: Oracle, More in detail Pl/sql

Comment: The second subset doesn't have a plushType or plushPrice, how do you expect to show `plushType, plushPrice for the customers of the second subset`?  I think you need to give a more concrete example *(ideally in SQL Fiddle)*

Comment: the second query defines a subset of customers. For these customer I want to run the first query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added this new answer that is more efficient:

```
with selected_customers (customerid) as (
  select customerid 
    from customers 
    where customerid < 4
  union
  select customerid
    from customers 
    left join foods fs on cs.customerid = fs.customerid 
    where fs.foodname = 'pizza'
)
select customerid, ps.plushtype, ps.plushprice
  from selected_customers cs
  left join plushes ps on cs.customerid = ps.customerid;
```

Answer (score 1):

This query will do:

```
select customerid, plushtype, plushprice
  from customers cs
  left join plushes ps on cs.customerid = ps.customerid
  where customerid in (
          select customerid 
            from customers 
            where customerid < 4
        )
     or customerid in (
          select customerid 
            from customers cs
            left join foods fs on cs.customerid = fs.customerid 
            where fs.foodname = 'pizza'
        );
```

Comment: You are right, but you are basing your answer on the fact the you can choose customer 6 independently from the second query. 
Imagine that you don't know in advance the second subset of customers retrieved by the second query. 

To make things clearer, I changed the where statement in the second query. Have a look

Comment: Modified, according to your new change.

Comment: Thank you :) I already tried this solution.. but it took more than 20 minutes to executing the query, then I stopped.... You know, nested query destroys efficiency

Comment: Hey, you keep moving the post (not fair) :)

Comment: Ahahah you are right, my friend. But that it is my real need, unfortunately